# Oracle Subquery Factoring Not Working For Function Call

Tags: performance, oracle11g, query-tuning

I'm using Oracle 11g. I have a query that takes 6 seconds to execute

```
 select *
   from tab1
  where exists (select 1
           from tab2
          where tab2.col1 = tab1.col1
            and tab2.col2 = pkg1.fn1('STRING'));
```

The highlighted function returns a constant value = 1. (The function has 1 query which when executed standalone, returns result in < 1 second.

If I hardcode 1 instead of calling the function, query returns same results in < 1 second.

I do not want to use RESULT_CACHE in function, etc. I want to rewrite the query so that it is faster.

**Approach 1: No time difference**
The query within the function is brought out and used as a subquery

```
and tab2.col2 = pkg1.fn1('STRING')
```

changed to

```
and tab2.col2 = (query within the function is written here)
```

**Approach 2: Time increased**
The query within the function is brought out and used as an inner join with the overall query within the exists clause.

**Approach 3: No change**

```
with factoring as (select pkg1.fn1('STRING') as return_val from dual)
 select *
   from tab1
  where exists (select 1
           from tab2, factoring
          where tab2.col1 = tab1.col1
            and tab2.col2 = factoring.return_val);
```

**Approach 4: No change**

```
with factoring as (select pkg1.fn1('STRING') as return_val from dual)
 select *
   from tab1, factoring
  where exists (select 1
           from tab2
          where tab2.col1 = tab1.col1
            and tab2.col2 = factoring.return_val);
```

**I want to understand below**
 1. why approach 3 and 4 didn't work
 2. how to optimize this query?

Comment: What do the execution plans show? In your first query, is changing from a function call to a literal changing the plan (e.g. which index is hit)? Is the function determinisitic, and can/should it be?

Comment: Execution plans have no difference when changed to literal. The function behaves like a deterministic function, but I don't want to change anything in the function. What can be done to the query?